# Combining cells in excel 2013 with internal formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to combine the contents of two cells each of which has different formats within the cells. (Only some words are bolded within the cells)

Using my goto formula =A1&";"A2 doesn't work as the bolden is applied to the entire contents.

Is there a way to keep the formats when combining?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. There is no way for that (without macros), Excel formulas doesn't consider formatting.